# Which one is the best WordPress plugin for test system with separate price for every test

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I have developed a WordPress website, I am being asked to find and integrate a plugin for the test system. Plugin requirements are as following:

- The plugin will have multiple choice questions and will have the option to have more than one test in it.
- every test will have a price and payment option with be pay with paypal.
- we can change passing percentage.
- only logged in user can perform the test. Only user and admin can see the result.

Please tell me if you have this kind of plugin, I am stucked and cant proceed., please please please point me to the solution if you can.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question,

you have to create new custom wordpress plugin and functionality because you can not get the ready plugin for this requirement.

In case, you can use the ready the plugin then you have to customise custom functionality as per your requirement.

So, I will suggest to you. you can create new plugin then user can easy to use.

Comment: can you develop wordpress plugins, if you develop this how much will you charge.? and how much time will you require.?